# Why is R having such a hard time converting a text file full of numbers into numbers?

Tags: r

The following short snipped of code:

```
> # Clear the console in RStudio 
> cat("\014")  
> 
> 
> setwd("C:/Users/name/Desktop/Project1v3/Fit_Index_Data/") 
> dataVectorTemp <- read.table("CFI1.txt", header = FALSE)
> dataVector <- as.numeric(dataVectorTemp) 
> mean(dataVector)
```

results in the following error message:

[image]

Perhaps it is because it's late at night as I write this, but I feel ***assaulted*** as to how a language like R can do such a good job of doing the wrong thing when it comes to something as simple as reading a `*.txt` file full of number in and finding the average.

I'm aware that R has to somehow convert these numbers from `chars` and `string` (from the original file) to floats (or `as.numeric`), but be darned if I know how to phrase my question other than to say that I am rather lost and defeated.

I'm not sure why I'm so boggled by this, but it has been as if R is playing a practical joke on me.

Comment: Try using ``mean(dataVector, na.rm = TRUE)``

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you are actually running the code in the same sequence as you are showing and with the same variables but the warning can be reproduced when you pass a dataframe to `mean` function. `read.table` would return a dataframe back.

Using `mtcars` as an example dataset :

```
mean(mtcars)
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
> In mean.default(mtcars) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

`mean` needs a vector to be passed, you can `unlist` the dataframe to convert to a vector which can be passed to `mean`.

```
mean(unlist(mtcars))
#[1] 39.60853
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try transforming all to numbers (and `NA` if not a number) and then use `na.rm = TRUE` within `mean` function.

```
dataVector <- sapply(dataVectorTemp, function(x) as.numeric(x))

mean(dataVector, na.rm = TRUE)
```